# how to mark end of data when writing over sockets using java7 async io

Tags: java, asynchronous, io

I am building a small client server connection where I need to send some payload and get a reply back.
I am using Java 7 Async IO. 
My requirement is

1. to receive the payload
2. parse the request
3. do some processing
4. write the response back

How can I mark the end of request from the client without closing the connection. I can see two options,

- Send -1,this implies another read step from server
- parse the request bytes as they come to get to know the end, this I want to avoid.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you will have either data separator (your option 1), but you have to be ABSOLUTELY sure that this data separator will NEVER be present in your data packet
or
you can prepend the packet with size information (i.e. have an equivalent of packet header)